# Error configuring mod_wsgi from source code

Tags: python, django, unix, debian, mod-wsgi

I'm trying to `./configure` mod_wsgi from source code per [these instructions](https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/quick-installation-guide.html). Overall I'm trying to get Django working with Python3 and Apache on a Google Cloud Compute Engine. It's using Debian 9. I installed Python 3.6 from Anaconda located in `/home/dhampton/anaconda3`.

I'm running into the following error:

```
dhampton@blog-instance-1:~/mod_wsgi-4.5.20$ ./configure
checking for apxs2... no
checking for apxs... no
checking for gcc... no
checking for cc... no
checking for cl.exe... no
configure: error: in `/home/dhampton/mod_wsgi-4.5.20':
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
See `config.log' for more details
dhampton@blog-instance-1:~/mod_wsgi-4.5.20$
```

The following is what's in the `config.log` file:

```
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by configure, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.69.  Invocation command line was

  $ ./configure 

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = blog-instance-1
uname -m = x86_64
uname -r = 4.9.0-4-amd64
uname -s = Linux
uname -v = #1 SMP Debian 4.9.51-1 (2017-09-28)

/usr/bin/uname -p = unknown
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = unknown
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = unknown
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /home/dhampton/anaconda3/bin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /usr/local/games
PATH: /usr/games


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:1889: checking for apxs2
configure:1923: result: no
configure:1889: checking for apxs
configure:1923: result: no
configure:2009: checking for gcc
configure:2039: result: no
configure:2102: checking for cc
configure:2149: result: no
configure:2205: checking for cl.exe
configure:2235: result: no
configure:2259: error: in `/home/dhampton/mod_wsgi-4.5.20':
configure:2261: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
See `config.log' for more details

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_env_CC_set=
ac_cv_env_CC_value=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

APXS='apxs'
CC=''
CFLAGS=''
CPPFLAGS=''
DEFS=''
DESTDIR=''
ECHO_C=''
ECHO_N='-n'
ECHO_T=''
EXEEXT=''
LDFLAGS=''
LDLIBS=''
LIBEXECDIR=''
LIBOBJS=''
LIBS=''
LTLIBOBJS=''
OBJEXT=''
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT=''
PACKAGE_NAME=''
PACKAGE_STRING=''
PACKAGE_TARNAME=''
PACKAGE_URL=''
PACKAGE_VERSION=''
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
PYTHON=''
SHELL='/bin/bash'
ac_ct_CC=''
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build_alias=''
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE}'
dvidir='${docdir}'
exec_prefix='NONE'
host_alias=''
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
pdfdir='${docdir}'
prefix='NONE'
program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
psdir='${docdir}'
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target_alias=''

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

/* confdefs.h */
#define PACKAGE_NAME ""
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
#define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
#define PACKAGE_STRING ""
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
#define PACKAGE_URL ""

configure: exit 1
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: seems like you don't have a c compiler installed, try to install https://gcc.gnu.org/

Comment: @doze That led to the answer. I wasn't using the `--installed flag` on apt when I tried checking if apache2 was installed. Installing apache installed gcc and now it passes this step. Thanks. How do I give you credit for answer?

Comment: glad that was helpful, i will post it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you have no C compiler installed, installing [gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/) will solve the problem

Comment: This was the answer that **led** to getting past the error. I did also have to install other dependencies as Alejandro mentioned in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

By your log I can see you will probably find a lot of dependencies not resolved to compile it (not only the compiler).

Try to find the package that match the missing dependency using for example the command:

```
$ apt-cache search apxs2
```

And installing after you find the right package:

```
$ sudo apt-get install apache2-dev
```

As you are compiling, probably you will need the development packages, it is for example apache2-dev. As  the previous message said, you need a compiler too, so install gcc:

```
$ sudo apt-get install gcc
```

Install too the binutils package to don't get crazy looking at many of the messages:

```
$ sudo apt-get install binutils
```

---

By the way, exist a package in Debian that could make your life easier, so if you want to avoid to compile it (and don't do the previous steps), try to run this:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3
```

I have not tried, but probably make some of the configurations described into the guide you provided as link.

Good luck!

Comment: Installing `apache2` and `apache2-dev` also installed `gcc` and `binutils` it looks like. Clearing up the errors I was having. I saw `libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3` but I wasn't sure if it was cause problems between the existing python installations and the one I did from anaconda.  Thanks for your answer.